# Spring Data JPA Query: Insert List Of Values

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have a `List<Integer> ids` and a `Integer singleId`. Is there a way to make `INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES()` for a lot of values using spring data JPA `@Query()`?
I need something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE 
    VALUES(ids[0], singleId),
    VALUES(ids[1], singleId),
    VALUES(ids[2], singleId),
    ...
```

Comment: No. JPA providers (some anyway) can batch insert objects into a single statement, but if you want to control the SQL, you'll have to write your own prepared statements yourself.

Comment: i think its better to create a list of your entity and then save that list